# Add css file to cshtml file?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add a css file to a basic html file (in /dashboard along with the css file) and it is not working:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Views/Dashboard/Dashboard.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h2 id="yes">Index</h2>
    <h1>@ViewBag.test</h1>

</body>
```

I have tried multiple ways, including adding the file to the contents folder, and adding

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

Is this a syntax issue? Or a lack of understanding of how the layout system works? Still wrapping my head around asp.net and MVC...

Comment: you didn't mentioned the problem

Comment: Remove the `<head>` tags (your view appears to be using a layout which is where the `<head>` tags are)

Comment: @StephenMuecke That didn't work. Is my path incorrect? You're referring to my first method, right?

Comment: _Is my path incorrect_ - how would I know :) - I'm commenting on the duplicate `<head>` elements that you trying to create. First just try moving your `<link ../>` into the layout `<head>` tags. And your browser console will tell you if the path is incorrect - it will generate a 404 Not Found (and if your layout is correct, then you use use `@section Styles` - not `Scripts`)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this below at end of the body tag

```
@section Scripts
{
  <link href="~/Content/yourcssname.css" rel="stylesheet" />
}
```

Comment: you're welcome Ryan, could you please vote for the answer :)

Comment: You do not put style sheets in the `Scripts` section

Comment: Voted for best answer

Answer (score 5):

You are **not** supposed to be loading CSS under the `@section Scripts`. There's a reason CSS is loaded first!

For example, check this reference here by Patrick Sexton: [Call CSS First](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/call-css-first.html)

> Ensuring the calls for CSS
> files come first helps ensure the browser gets it first. This saves
> time by reducing network calls and not letting javascript activity
> delay the browser from getting CSS

### Real Solution - Loading your CSS First

#### Step #1

If you want to load different CSS files depending on the `.cshtml` file, and assuming they all use the same `_Layout.cshtml`, you can do something like this:

On your `_Layout.cshtml`, in between your `<head>` HTML tag, write this:

```
@RenderSection("Stylesheets", required: true)
```

Putting this in your `<head>` tag will ensure it gets loaded first!

Note: The `required: true` part is *optional*.

#### Step #2

Then, on your `.cshtml` Views, add this at the top:

```
@section Stylesheets {

}
```

And inside there, load your `<link>` tags.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, this section (`Stylesheets`) can be used for more than just stylesheets. It can be used for everything in the layout pages that needs to be in `<head>`. So it should be named `Head`.

Comment: @RoyCohen The OP question was about adding CSS to `cshtml` files - hence my response solely mentions CSS (so I gave it the name of Stylesheets). Certainly, you're right in that it can be used for more than just stylesheets. You could throw in there anything regarding layout too. In fact, you could even create any amount of Sections, and have them loaded independently in your `cshtml` files if that aids in your development - but I believe more than a few are not good. I personally always use a Stylesheets section and a Scripts section, as I change the contents of those a lot in between files.